# I have created 2 pages template in jaspersoft studio.but when i preview it then shows 17 pages.how this possible?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have created a report template with 3 pages but when I preview a report it shows me 1 of 17 pages.. ideally it should show 1 of 3 pages.. I am not getting why remaining 14 pages are increased.

Comment: Repeated same records?
Does your query correct?

Comment: I checked, not any one record is repeated as well as connection query also correct..

Comment: I can't understand the problem what you're facing.
Please explain more detail.

Comment: Such things can only be explained after seeing the JRXML files involved.